# Google Cloud Speech to Text API stopped working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I signed up for Google Cloud Speech to Text API for a project I am undertaking. This morning, I was able to convert speech to text successfully. In the evening, I resumed the work and all of a sudden, it stops working. It doesn't take any input and upon keyword interrupt I get the following message. I am not sure why it has suddenly decided not to work. I restarted my laptop thinking it would be some microphone issue. Then, I downloaded the code and re-ran, yet no positive outcome. Below is the message I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ajayshah/Downloads/s2t.py", line 174, in <module>
 main()
File "/Users/ajayshah/Downloads/s2t.py", line 167, in main
 responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
File "/Users/ajayshah/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/helpers.py", line 81, in streaming_recognize
 return super(SpeechHelpers, self).streaming_recognize(
File "/Users/ajayshah/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/services/speech/client.py", line 605, in streaming_recognize
  response = rpc(requests, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
File "/Users/ajayshah/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 142, in __call__
  return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/ajayshah/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
  return retry_target(
File "/Users/ajayshah/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 218, in retry_target
  time.sleep(sleep)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Maybe an API token expired?

Comment: Nope. It will throw an error for that, if it was the case.

Comment: Service is working. I run a small test (link below) and it worked successfully. Have you check if your credential information have not expired or its available to your project? You can do a [small test on cloud shell editor](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/libraries#installing_the_client_library).